# How can I track everything (all code) with Chronon?

Tags: java, debugging, chronon

I use Chronon recording debugger with a piece of Java code. The piece itself is small, but uses a lot of libaries that do some magical things I'd like to see and understand. I tried setting up Chronon to record what happens in ALL classes (yes, I'm aware this could be awfully slow) by setting the class name pattern to `*`, but it fails with an error:

```
java.com.chronon3.sb.recorder.config.SettingsLoadException:
Cannot just use '*', atleast a namespace must be specified, eg com.mycompany.**
```

Is there a way to work around this or do I really need to go through all of my JARs and list all the prefixes from there?

Comment: Try using `**.*`, it may help or may be '**.java' to be more precise.

Comment: I tried it and it seemed to work (gave no warning), but it didn't record anything. `**`, however, did work! :)

Answer (score 1):

It was as simple as using `**` instead.

Chronon docs: https://chronon.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DOC/Include+and+Exclude+patterns

I expected it to be slow, but it's so ridiculously slow that it doesn't really make much sense. I got good results specifying a few namespaces, and this way it's much much faster.